# Android studio can't choose Process for debugging with device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

i'am new in android
i want to debug apps with device, i already install all the component (sdk, adb driver, google usb driver), and the phone setting is all turned on for developer mode
but still unable to do it

[image]

why the OK button is disabled?
Thanks...

Comment: This may happen if you accidentally click the _Attach Debugger to Android Process_ button, rather than the _Debug 'app'_ button.

Answer (score 1):

Connect your device as Camera(PTP) from USB connection option and allow your USB debugging from settings.